# Message grade build is showing error

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I am beginner in android. I had installed the android studio. Without writing a code I executed the already existing file.

But it is showing me some error. I had attached the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: The error is " execution failed to task app process debug mainfest > mainfest merger failed: uses: sdk min sdk version9 cannot be smaller then version 14 "

Comment: Error gives a solution, Your app `minSdk` version can not be smaller than the one that is declared in Library

Comment: Hi Arshan, please format your question to use Markdown, include the actual image (and not just a link), explain what you've tried so far, and clarify what you mean by "the existing file".  Thanks.

Comment: Hi wizard I already tried it but it is showing me another error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pack"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

in **build.gradle** file you see that code in `defaultConfig` section

change `minSdkVersion` 9 to **14 or above**

Because you used libraries need SDK ver 14 or above(they did n't complied in SDK 9)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using support library version **26**. For example, you're using the following dependency:

```
com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1
```

Starting from support library version 26, [minimum SDK version is 14](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#26-0-0):

> The minimum SDK version has been increased to 14. As a result, many
>   APIs that existed only for compatibility with pre-14 API levels have
>   been deprecated. Clients of these APIs should migrate to their
>   framework equivalents as noted in the reference page for each
>   deprecated API.

So, you need either increase your `minSdkVersion` to 14 or using support library version **25**.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the end of your gradle file -

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```